# wisyhtml5 (rails-4) image button does not work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I use the `bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails` gem with Rails-4.

My problem is that the image button inserts an (almost) empty `img` tag, and the image url gets lost:

```
<img alt="">
```

[image]

[image]

The link button works fine.

Some idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After update a gem bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails from version 0.3.3.1 to version 0.3.3.6, the inserting images works correctly.